# Canon XS vs XSi

Tags: canon-450d, canon-1000d

Can someone explain the main differences (pros/cons) between the Canon XS and XSi?

Comment: I think this question largely falls in the same shopping category as "Macbook Air vs. Macbook Pro?" in this post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/. Discussion on Meta: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/why-are-you-voting-down-my-xs-vs-xsi-question

Comment: The question is not a shopping question in the sense of "which is better" or "which should I buy", rather it asks "what are the differences between two cameras?" We allow many other similar questions that compare two pieces of gear.

Comment: @MichaelClark I get your point, but does it really matter herein almost 2014?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DPReview's done a great job on that](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos1000d/page2.asp).

Highlights (advantage XSi):

- Higher resolution
- Better autofocus
- Highlight tone priority
- Improved viewfinder

Of these, the sensor & processor are worth the price of admission.

Comment: Are you by any chance mixing up [XS (1000D)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_1000D) with [XTi (400D)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_400D)? XS was released *after* [XSi (450D)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_450D) and is a "downgraded" model. The DPReview article doesn't mention nor does provide a comparison to the XS.

Comment: XS = http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos1000d/
XSi = http://www.dpreview.com/news/0801/08012403canoneos450d.asp

Comment: You're right - I grabbed the wrong link.  I'll edit to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Mainly the XSi will have a higher resolution 12/10MP, more focus points 9/7, larger LCD screen 3in/2.5in, and a faster continuous drive 3.5fps/3fps.

They are more similar then they are different.  If the price difference is much, I would save the money and spend it on a lens.